# Run-length encoding and group by

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am still new to using the functionality of `data.table`.  My objective is to use `rle()` or `rleid()` while grouping by multiple variables.  `rle()` is not a typical summary statistic.

In my test data set below, I aim to count the consecutive recurring records where unique bikes (`bike_id`) are at the same location `address`, and then group by date and by `bike_id`.

Some test data would be the following :

```
> dat
                   time bike_id          address
 1: 2017-11-22 15:45:34       1        Waters Rd
 2: 2017-11-22 15:50:16       1        Waters Rd
 3: 2017-11-22 16:00:03       1   Washington Ave
 4: 2017-11-22 16:10:03       1   Washington Ave
 5: 2017-11-22 16:20:02       1   Washington Ave
 6: 2017-11-22 16:30:02       2       Shady Lane
 7: 2017-11-22 16:40:03       2     Comstock Ave
 8: 2017-11-22 16:50:02       2     Comstock Ave
 9: 2017-11-22 17:00:02       2     Comstock Ave
10: 2017-11-22 17:10:02       2     Comstock Ave
11: 2017-11-22 17:20:03       3   Scranton Drive
12: 2017-11-22 17:30:03       3   Scranton Drive
13: 2017-11-22 17:40:03       3   Scranton Drive
14: 2017-11-22 17:50:03       3       Shady Lane
15: 2017-11-22 18:00:04       3   Scranton Drive
16: 2017-11-23 18:10:03       1       Shady Lane
17: 2017-11-23 18:20:03       1       Shady Lane
18: 2017-11-23 18:30:02       1       Shady Lane
19: 2017-11-23 18:40:03       1       Shady Lane
20: 2017-11-23 18:50:03       1       Shady Lane
21: 2017-11-23 19:00:03       2      Lovers Lane
22: 2017-11-23 19:10:02       2 Mulholland Drive
23: 2017-11-23 19:20:03       2 Mulholland Drive
24: 2017-11-23 19:30:02       2 Mulholland Drive
25: 2017-11-23 19:40:03       2 Mulholland Drive
                   time bike_id          address
```

I know that using `rle(dat$address)` will produce the third column in the desired output below, but am unsure how to group by with `rle()` in `data.table`

```
> output
         date bike_id rle
1  2017-11-22       1   2
2  2017-11-22       1   3
3  2017-11-22       2   1
4  2017-11-22       2   4
5  2017-11-22       3   3
6  2017-11-22       3   1
7  2017-11-22       3   1
8  2017-11-23       1   5
9  2017-11-23       2   1
10 2017-11-23       2   4
```

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Here is the sample data:

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(time = structure(c(1511383534.43394, 1511383816.49785, 
1511384403.94561, 1511385003.17654, 1511385602.47887, 1511386202.99895, 
1511386803.18361, 1511387402.98233, 1511388002.69461, 1511388602.5818, 
1511389203.52712, 1511389803.652, 1511390403.26619, 1511391003.79218, 
1511391604.30061, 1511478603.55103, 1511479203.60366, 1511479802.97132, 
1511480403.45374, 1511481003.12783, 1511481603.34055, 1511482202.62777, 
1511482803.66405, 1511483402.83378, 1511484003.46605), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), bike_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), address = c("Waters Rd", 
"Waters Rd", "Washington Ave", "Washington Ave", "Washington Ave", 
"Shady Lane", "Comstock Ave", "Comstock Ave", "Comstock Ave", 
"Comstock Ave", "Scranton Drive", "Scranton Drive", "Scranton Drive", 
"Shady Lane", "Scranton Drive", "Shady Lane", "Shady Lane", "Shady Lane", 
"Shady Lane", "Shady Lane", "Lovers Lane", "Mulholland Drive", 
"Mulholland Drive", "Mulholland Drive", "Mulholland Drive")), .Names = c("time", 
"bike_id", "address"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x10300d178>)
```

EDIT:

A unique case in where the code in the answer below produces an incorrect result:

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(bike_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), lon = c(-76.968, 
-76.968, -76.968, -72.141, -72.141, -72.141), lat = c(38.924, 
38.924, 38.924, -39.219, -39.219, -39.219), time = structure(c(1511383534.49273, 
1511383816.52327, 1511384403.97359, 1511385003.20305, 1511385602.50507, 
1511299803.02598), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), .Names = c("bike_id", 
"lon", "lat", "time"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x10300d178>)

> dat
   bike_id     lon     lat                time
1:       1 -76.968  38.924 2017-11-22 15:45:34
2:       1 -76.968  38.924 2017-11-22 15:50:16
3:       1 -76.968  38.924 2017-11-22 16:00:03
4:       1 -72.141 -39.219 2017-11-22 16:10:03
5:       1 -72.141 -39.219 2017-11-22 16:20:02
6:       1 -72.141 -39.219 2017-11-21 16:30:03

> dat[, .(date = as.Date(time)[1], n = .N), .(bike_id, grp = rleid(lat, lon))][, grp := NULL][]
```

produces:

```
   bike_id       date n
1:       1 2017-11-22 3
2:       1 2017-11-22 3
```

expected:

```
   bike_id       date n
1:       1 2017-11-22 3
2:       1 2017-11-22 2
3:       1 2017-11-21 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `rleid` in `data.table`

```
dat[, .(date = as.Date(time)[1], n = .N), .(bike_id, grp = rleid(address))][, grp := NULL][]
```

---

If there are multiple 'date' for each grouping variables (second data), then the previous one will select only the first 'date' (`[1]`).  Suppose, we wanted to get both the 'date' then either use

```
dat[, .(date = unique(as.Date(time)), n = .N),, .(bike_id, grp = rleid(lon, lat))]
#   bike_id grp       date n
#1:       1   1 2017-11-22 3
#2:       1   2 2017-11-22 3
#3:       1   2 2017-11-21 3
```

But, this also have multiple rows for each group.  If we need only a single row per group, either create a `list` column (preserves the `class`)

```
dat[, .(date = list(unique(as.Date(time))), n = .N),, .(bike_id, grp = rleid(lon, lat))]
#   bike_id grp                  date n
#1:       1   1            2017-11-22 3
#2:       1   2 2017-11-22,2017-11-21 3
```

Or `paste` the `unique` elements together

#### Update

Based on the update in the OP's post for expected output (from second dataset), we need to use the 'date' also as grouping variable

```
dat[, .(n = .N),, .(bike_id, date = as.Date(time), grp = rleid(lon, lat))][, grp := NULL][]
#   bike_id       date n
#1:       1 2017-11-21 1
#2:       1 2017-11-22 3
#3:       1 2017-11-22 2
```

Comment: thanks, this works, with the caveat that `as.Date()` should specify timezone.   Could you explain what the last part of the formula does ? `[, grp := NULL]` ?

Comment: @the_darkside  Because we created a grouping variable with `rleid`, in the next step, I removed that column by assigning to NULL.

Comment: thanks for the explanation @akrun.  Could you explain the case above which I added to the end of my question, in which the code produces an unexpected result?

Comment: @the_darkside  In the updated one, which one is the grouping variable?  I don't find any `address`

Comment: it would be `(lat, lon)` as opposed to `address`.  Any idea why two unique dates would not be appearing in the output, re: the updated question?

Comment: @the_darkside  IN the example you gave, it gives me `n=3` for each entry.  Isn't that the expected one.  Regarding that question about dates, in the first example, I had seen only a single unique date.  But, in this case, there are 2 unique dates, and only the first one we selected with `[1]`.  If you need both, then either you need to have a `list` column or paste it as `string`

Comment: @the_darkside  ie. `dat[, .(date = unique(as.Date(time)), n = .N),, .(bike_id, grp = rleid(lon, lat))]` gives 3 rows, if you need only 2, then `paste` it  or create a `list` (will keep the date format `dat[, .(date = list(unique(as.Date(time))), n = .N),, .(bike_id, grp = rleid(lon, lat))]`

Comment: @the_darkside  Just saw your expected.  I will update the answer

Comment: @the_darkside Are you doing some ordering in the expected output.  In that case `dat[, .(n = .N),, .(bike_id, date = as.Date(time), grp = rleid(lon, lat))][order(-n)]`